# Python: Do Python Lists keep a count for len() or does it count for each call?

Tags: python

If I keep calling len() on a very long list, am I wasting time, or does it keep an int count in the background?

Comment: This always bugged me. especially when my profiler told me I spent 2.2 seconds of a program that ran for one minute calling this function.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Don't worry: Of course it saves the count and thus `len()` on lists is a pretty cheap operation. Same is true for strings, dictionaries and sets, by the way!

Comment: I believe it keeps a count like index of last item+1 or something, and calls value of len() from that memory location. Am I right?

Answer (score 46):

And one more way to find out how it's done is <del>[to look it up on Google Code Search](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#ggVSD6_h0Ho/Python-2.5/Objects/listobject.c&q=package:python-2.5%20listobject.c%20lang:c&l=370)</del> [look at the source on GitHub](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.5/Objects/listobject.c#L379), if you don't want to download the source yourself.

```
static Py_ssize_t list_length(PyListObject *a)
{
    return a->ob_size;
}
```

Answer (score 32):

[`len` is an O(1) operation](http://books.google.com/books?id=JnR9hQA3SncC&pg=PA478&dq=Python+len+big+O&ei=JUbRSYPqGofqkwTy9_ihAQ).

Answer (score 14):

Write your program so that it's **optimised for clarity and easily maintainable**. Is your program clearer with a call to `len(foo)`? Then do that.

Are you worried about the time taken? Use the [`timeit` module in the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit) to *measure* the time taken, and see whether it is significant in your code.

You will, like most people, very likely be wrong in your guesses about which parts of your program are slowest. Avoid the temptation to guess, and instead measure it to find out.

Remember that **premature optimisation is the root of all evil**, in the words of Donald Knuth. Only focus on the speed of code that you have *measured* the speed of, to know whether the benefit would be worth the cost of changing how it works.

Comment: I am a coder just months into my job and I endorse both practices. The timer stuff offers a two-lines defense against a large body of conventional wisdom ("SELECT.. RANDOM is too expensive") that will be hurled your way.

Answer (score 5):

The question has been answered (`len` is O(1)), but here's how you can check for yourself:

```
$ python -m timeit -s "l = range(10)" "len(l)"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.119 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s "l = range(1000000)" "len(l)"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.131 usec per loop
```

Yep, not really slower.

Comment: Just for future readers: This isn't a valid test for Python 3 anymore. Nowadays `range()` returns a generator instead of a pre-made list.

Answer (score 4):

A Python "list" is really a resizeable array, not a linked list, so it stores the size somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite late to the party, but I just did a test and got some interesting results:

```py
import timeit, statistics

test_arr = list(range(1000000))

# Just call len() every time
def test1(arr):
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        j = arr[len(arr)-1]

# Store the result of len()
def test2(arr):
    l = len(arr)
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        j = arr[l-1]

print("Running test 1...")
t1 = timeit.repeat(lambda: test1(test_arr), number=int(2e2), repeat=4)
print("Test 1 results:")
print(t1)

print("Running test 2...")
t2 = timeit.repeat(lambda: test2(test_arr), number=int(2e2), repeat=4)
print("Test 2 results:")
print(t2)

m1 = statistics.mean(t1)
m2 = statistics.mean(t2)
avg = round(100 * abs(m2-m1)/m1, 2)
sign = "quicker" if m1-m2 > 0 else "slower"
print(f"On average, test 2 was {avg} {sign} than test 1")
```

Results:

```
Running test 1...
Test 1 results:
[15.189714099979028, 15.160469999769703, 15.17295220005326, 15.072236399864778]
Running test 2...
Test 2 results:
[8.17264029989019, 8.191439799964428, 8.171442999970168, 8.208112000022084]
On average, test 2 was 45.96 quicker than test 1
```

It's a very crude test and I'm sure somebody can improve upon it (or point out a mistake), but it appears that it is indeed significantly quicker to call `len` only once and save it to a variable, rather than calling it repeatedly (which I believe is what the poster was asking).

Comment: I'd say the benchmark is a bit misleading, since it does no other real work than repeatedly call `len()` (or not call it). For a function that would do other work too, the price of `len()` is likely to disappear...

Comment: As an aside, you can shave off about 17% from `test1`'s time just by aliasing the global `len` into a local. Global/module lookups can be expensive in CPython too.

Comment: Truth appears in algorithms. Thank you.