# Creating anagram detector

Tags: python, anagram

I'm having trouble getting this anagram function to work. The aim is for 
the function to take 2 strings `abc` and `cba`, convert them into a list;
sort them in to alphabetical order, compare the elements of the list and print whether they are anagrams or not.

My code is as follows...

```
def anagram(str1, str2):
    x = str1
    y = str2

    x1 = x.sort()
    y1 = y.sort()

    if (x1) == (y1):
        print("Anagram is True")
    else:
        print("Anagram is False")

str1 = str('abc')
str2 = str('cba')

print(anagram(str1, str2))
```

Comment: what are the types of x and y? Do they have `sort` method? What is `x.sort()` doing?

Comment: You can't `.sort` strings and once they're lists, note that `.sort()` is **in-place**, and returns `None`. Also, there seems no point to locally aliasing e.g. `str1` to `x`.

Comment: `sorted(x) == sorted(y)`

Comment: Note that your whole function can be simplified to `print("Anagram is {!r}".format(sorted(str1) == sorted(str2)))`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you can't call `String.sort()`. Try changing:

```
x1 = x.sort()
y1 = y.sort()
```

to:

```
x1 = sorted(x)
y1 = sorted(y)
```

Answer (score 1):

### The specific issue

`x.sort()` works in-place if `x` is a list. This means the sort method changes the objects internal representation. It also returns `None` which is the reason why it doesn't work as intended.

If `x` is a string, there is no `.sort()` method as strings are immutable.

I recommend to use the `sorted()` function instead, which returns the sorted string.

### The more general issues

There are two more general issues:

1. **Runtime**: This is an O(log(n) * n) solution
2. **Unicode** modifiers and compound glyphs
3. **Print**: You print the value, but instead you should return the result. How would you test your code?

#### Unicode modifiers

Lets say you wrote the function more compact:

```py
def is_anagram(a: str, b: str) -> bool:
    return sorted(a) == sorted(b)
```

This works fine for normal characters, but fails for compound glyphs. For example, the thumbsup / thumbsdown emoji can be modified to have different colors. The change in color is actually a second unicode "character" which gives the skin tone. The modifier and the previous character belong together, but `sorted` just looks at the code points. Which results in this:

```
>>> is_anagram("", "")
True  # <-- This should be False!
```

Sublime Text shows the actual code points:

[image]

You can easily fix this by using the grapheme package:

```py
from grapheme import graphemes
def is_anagram(a: str, b: str) -> bool:
    return sorted(graphemes(a)) == sorted(graphemes(b))
```

#### Runtime

You can get O(n) runtime if you don't sort, but instead count characters:

```py
from collections import Counter
from grapheme import grahemes

def is_anagram(a: str, b: str) -> bool:
    return not (Counter(grapheme(a)) - Counter(grapheme(b)))
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot call `.sort()` on a string, nor should you be cause that is actually a method that sorts a list in place and will not return anything. instead, use `sorted(x)`

```
>>> def anagram(str1, str2):
    x1 = sorted(str1)
    y1 = sorted(str2)

    if (x1) == (y1):
        print("Anagram is True")
    else:
        print("Anagram is False")


>>> anagram('abc','bca')
Anagram is True
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks for the help.