# Is it inefficient to use the len() function in the while loop condition?

Tags: python, performance, time-complexity

Consider the following code to store the characters of a string in a list:

```
s = "apple"
i = 0
l = []
while i < len(s):
  l.append(s[i])
  i += 1
```

The code evaluates the length of the string in the while loop condition. This code is simple and easy to understand, and I see this type of code fairly often. Is writing the while condition this way less efficient than evaluating the length prior to the loop?

My understanding is that this changes the time complexity from O(n) to O(n^2). Is this correct?

Comment: Less efficient than what? What bothers you in the way `len` is used here?

Comment: It is inefficient in the sense that ``len(s)`` never changes but is still looked up during every iteration. You could store the result of ``len(s)`` in a variable and use that variable in the condition. But that's really just a micro-optimization. Btw, you get the same result by simple writing ``l = list(s)``, no need for a loop.

Comment: Slightly but in most cases it just doesn't matter. Performance optimization can lead to less readable code (and needs a lot of work). Therefore it should only be done where it is worth it.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Wouldn't this change the complexity from O(n) to O(n^2)? I thought this was a big deal.

Comment: @Abhilash No. The string length is stored as an explicit value for the string object (unlike null-terminated strings in C) so it's just an additional lookup of a value plus additional conversion to a Python int object to return it but all happens in constant time.

Comment: No, algorithmically, it is not inefficient. `len(s)` where `s` is a string (or really, an built-in container) is an O(1) operation.

Comment: Also, you would never write a `while` loop for something like this, you would generally just iterate directly over the container with a for loop, i.e. `for c in s: l.append(c)` however, in this case, you can just do `l = list(s)`. Or maybe you can just use `s` directly, depending on why you were building a list to begin with. It seems to me you are coming from a language like C. You generally don't write code like you would in C in Python. Python is a much higher-level language. Honestly, if you see python code like this a lot, I would use other resources.

Comment: I'd like to know more about the len function and the string object. Is there somewhere I can check the source code for len()?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga This was a contrived example, albeit a bad one. I wanted to share an example using the len() function in the loop condition, which I have seen often.

Comment: Yes, CPython is open source on github.

Comment: @Abhilash--more answers to this and [answer 2 shows len soure code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699177/python-do-python-lists-keep-a-count-for-len-or-does-it-count-for-each-call).  Since len is O(1) the time complexity of the while loop should be O(n) not O(n^2).

Comment: @Abhilash really? I use Python every day in a professional setting and I *rarely* see while loops. Generally in Python, you are working with iterators, and not with the index-based loops you'd see in a language like C. I'm not saying they aren't used at all, but if you say you see something like this "all the time" I have to wonder about the context. But feel free to ignore my advice.

Answer (score -4):

As far as I know everybody uses len. But it has one downside.
In Strings. Len returns the number of characters in a string. It counts spaces, punctuation, all characters the same. We must be careful with taking the len of a None variable—this fails.
In Empty fields: The second len call tests an empty string. This string has zero characters but is not None.
If it's a TypeError: Len relies on the type of the variable passed to it. A NoneType has no len built-in support.

Comment: The point wasn't to use len but to call it repeatedly although the result would always be the same.